# Ability to favorite comments & answers

Tags: feature-request

I really think that it would be useful to be able to favorite comments and answers in addition to questions. A lot of times I find an answer or comment that I want to keep for future reference, but I can only favorite the question. This is problematic when there is a lot of activity with the question that makes it hard to find the comment (or answer) I was looking for. Sometimes I also forget what I am looking for because the question alone means nothing to me and I can't remember that I favorited it for a comment.

Is it just me who thinks this would be a useful feature?

Comment: Favoriting a comment would be problematic, as comments are by definition ephemeral.

Comment: For folks like me :) ephemeral definition: lasting for a very short time.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately only questions can be favorited, and afaik there are no plans to make it possible to favorite answers. Your only options are to

- favorite the question
- manage bookmarks yourself by selecting the "share" link on the post containing the comment